# CALayer Troubles when loading an image from a UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, xcode4, uiimageview, calayer, layer

I have a UIViewController with a UIImageView (imageView), and I'm defining several layers that will be nested in the imageview as follows in viewDidLoad:

```
//container layer - the very top layer
CALayer *containerLayer = [CALayer layer];
containerLayer.opacity = 0;
containerLayer.bounds = [self.imageView.layer frame];

// Holder Layer
CALayer *holderLayer = [CALayer layer];
holderLayer.opacity = 0;
holderLayer.bounds = self.imageView.bounds;

// Hierarchy layers
[containerLayer setValue:holderLayer forKey:@"__holderLayer"];
[containerLayer addSublayer:holderLayer];

[self.imageView.layer addSublayer:containerLayer];
```

I have the following code that works when loading an image from a UIImagePicker :

```
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImageView *newImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.imageView.frame];

    CGRect frame = self.imageView.frame;

    newImgView.image = image;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    newImgView.layer.frame = frame;
    newImgView.layer.opacity = .9;
    newImgView.layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;

    CALayer * containerLayer = self.imageView.layer.sublayers[0];

    if (containerLayer != nil)
    {

        [containerLayer setValue:newImgView.layer forKey:@"__imageLayer"];


        CALayer * holderLayer = [containerLayer valueForKey:@"__holderLayer"];
        if (holderLayer != nil)
        {
            //!!!!!line below doesn't work!!!
            //[holderLayer addSublayer:newImgView.layer];

            //line below works!
            [self.imageView.layer addSublayer:newImgView.layer];
        }   
    }
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
    [self checkAndPrintLayers];
```

so the first nested layer is containerLayer, then holderLayer, and I'm expecting to add various images as sublayers to the holderLayer and then manipulate it. However, calling

```
  [holderLayer addSublayer:newImgView.layer];
```

doesn't work; the imageView stays blank. However, calling

```
[self.imageView.layer addSublayer:newImgView.layer];
```

and adding a sublayer to the top layer works just dandy. 
Am I missing something obvious here? Would love any suggestions.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Because

holderLayer and containerLayer are **transparent** *(holderLayer.opacity = 0 / containerLayer.opacity = 0)*,

Make it,

```
 //container layer - the very top layer
CALayer *containerLayer = [CALayer layer];
containerLayer.opacity = 1.0;
containerLayer.bounds = [self.imageView.layer frame];

// Holder Layer
CALayer *holderLayer = [CALayer layer];
holderLayer.opacity = 1.0;
holderLayer.bounds = self.imageView.bounds;
```

Comment: I Set those thinking that the opacity was blocking the image - but you're right! thank you!